# How to draw an open polygon in R

Tags: r, polygons

How can I create open polygons using R like these two examples:
[image: Two open polygons]

Comment: This question is a little vague. Do you mean how do create open polygons in R's plotting environment?

Comment: Yes in R plotting environment. Ggplot2 is not absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A little vague on what your use will be for this, but `geom_path` within the package `ggplot2` is a fairly simple approach.

First create a data frame, with `x` and `y` being your cartesian coordinates for all vertices:

```
df <- data.frame(plot = c(rep(1, 3), rep(2, 4)),
                 x = c(1, 0, 2, 0.5, 0, 2, 2.5),
                 y = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1))
```

Now plot:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, group = 1)) +
  geom_path(size = 1) + 
  facet_grid(. ~ plot) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

If you want more flexibility with customization, I suggest you create a separate, more detailed question.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to use `ggplot` you can do a similar thing as @DaveGruenewald with the native `plot` function.

Just do:

```
plot(c(0.5, 0, 2), c(1, 0, 0), type='l')
plot(c(0.5, 0, 2, 2.5), c(1, 0, 0, 1), type='l')
```

to get plots similar to @DaveGruenewald.